# fill the input type hidden from selected multiple option on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input that have type like this:

```
<input class="emailSend" name="emailSend" type="hidden">
```

Then I have a multiple select option like this

```
<div class="controls">
      <select id="email" multiple data-rel="chosen" class="input-xlarge" name="email[]">
          <?php
              foreach ($atasan as $data) {
                  echo "<option value='" . $data['email'] . "'>" . $data['email'] . "</option>";
              }
        ?>

       </select>
   </div>
```

My problem is, I want to fill that hidden input from the option that selected from multiple select option. So let say, the selected option is 'email1', 'email2', 'email3' then would be affected to hidden type like this 'email1, email2, email3'.

I have try this for 3 hour in jquery and I am stuck. My code is like this.

```
$("#email").change(function() {

        var elements = $("#email option:selected").length;
        var input = $(".emailSend");

        $(".emailSend").html("");
        $.each($("#email option:selected"), function(/*index, element*/) {

            input.val(input.val() + $(this).html() + ", ");
            if (index < elements - 1) {
               //code to remove last comma
               //any idea ?

            }
        });
    });
```

So appreciated for the help...

**EDIT**  Here is the fiddle :[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fadly_Dzil_Massere/z69q4a1s/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/incept0/z69q4a1s/4/) now that I see what you meant by looking at the fiddle you made.

this is actually all you need to do...

**Updated to include spaces between the addresses!**

```
  $("#email").on('change', function() {
       var thisval = $(this).val() + '';
       var myarr = thisval.split(',');
       var newval = '';
       myarr.forEach(function(i,v) {
           newval += i + ' , ';            
       });
       newval = newval.slice(0, newval.length - 3);
       $("#emailsend").val(newval); 
  });
```

> **Commented Version** (*for learning and stuff*)

```
   $("#email").on('change', function() {

       //the extra space at the end is to typecast to string
       var thisval = $(this).val() + '';

       //takes string of comma separated values and puts them
       //into an array
       var myarr = thisval.split(',');

       //Initialize a new string variable and loop through 
       //the array we just created with MDN's forEach()
       var newval = '';
       myarr.forEach(function(i,v) {

           //add to the string through each iteration, 
           //including comma with spaces
           newval += i + ' , ';

       });

       //use .slice() to trim three characters off the
       //end of the final string. (strip final comma)
       newval = newval.slice(0, newval.length - 3);

       //and last but not least, assign our newly created 
       //and properly formatted string to our input element. 
       $("#emailsend").val(newval);

  });
```

Comment: You know, it not really success, coz when first selected give result : "email1," . The second selected is "email1, email1, email2,"

Comment: This code does not do that, but I will check the fiddle and see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks, but there are not space like emai1, email2, email3. There like email1,email2,email3. Btw, so silly on me.